# Need help understanding the behavior of a request in IIS pipeline

Tags: c#, .net, azure, iis, iis-10

lately I am working on a case of unwanted redirects on our Azure hosted ASP .NET Core app which uses IIS. We have a problem with request containing two HTTP/HTTPS prefixes. I entered the Failed Request Tracing logs and see this (look at the RequestURL value):

[image]

[image]

Which then later gets shortened to this:
[image]

Anybody can help me understand why it happens? It happens before the request enters the rewrite pipeline, and even then, we don't have any rewrite rules which could cause it.

Our IIS rewrite rule after which redirection is happening:

```
<rule name="Add trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*[^/])$"  ignoreCase="true"/>
    <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^(.+?)/$" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="(.*?)\.html$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="(.*?)\.xml$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="(.*?)\.aspx$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(.*?)?(/?)(siteassets|globalassets|contentassets|SysSiteAssets|bundles|api|papirfly|dist|Static/HouseProductDemo|mini-profiler-resources|custom-routes|auth0|dam.papirfly)\/" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(.*?)?(/?)(robots.txt|favicon.ico|Sitemap.xml|sitemap-index.xml)" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(.*?)?(/?)(modules/Protected|EPiServer|EPiServer/CMS/admin|util|modulesbin|IndexingService/IndexingService.svc)" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(.*?)?(/?)(productsOverviewAsync|languageSelectorAsync)" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(.*?)?(/?)(documentationListAsync|downloadAndOrderItemsAsync|videoListAsync|commerceDocumentLibraryAsync)" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(.*?)?(/?)(GatedContentPageAsync)" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/.*/sitemap.xml$" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^(https?:/[^/]+){2,}" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}/" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Those look like _script-kiddie hacker-bots_ testing your site for vulnerabilities.

Comment: _"We have a problem with request containing two HTTP/HTTPS prefixes"_ - that's not actually possible: HTTP requests don't actually contain the URI scheme (they _only really_ exist in a browser's address bar, honestly)  and anyway, Azure's App Service front-end load-balancers will reject malformed HTTP requests.

Comment: Anything occurred in the very first row came from outside of IIS pipeline. This, if this is all you can provide, no one can explain why that specific URL was used. Like the other comment indicated, it didn’t usually come from a legit source.

Comment: This request came actually from us when we noticed that it's possible to make a redirect from URL parameter, we wanted to investigate the issue.

Comment: The edits of adding the rewrite rule do not help either, as this rule alone won't lead to the kind of URLs you dislike. Please hire an experienced consultant and share more details with him/her on the investigation. Stack Overflow, however, isn't the right place.

Comment: The format of the RequestURL `"http://rock-dev-web-01__06b0:80/http:/wp.pl"` looks incorrect. You may need to check the request sent by the client as well as the configuration on the server side to determine what is causing this incorrect URL.

Answer (score 0):

*"We have a problem with request containing two HTTP/HTTPS prefixes"*

- First, <sub>(and at risk of being accused of pedantry)</sub> they're not called "HTTP/HTTPS prefixes" - they're called *URI schemes*.
- Second, the request you logged there does not actually contain two URI schemes; I'll explain...

But before that, please have a quick read [through part 3 the current IETF specification that defines what a URI is and to learn terminology for its syntactical components](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3).

- The `/http:/wp.pl` text in your log *does look like the start of a new URI* when taken out of context, but it was still interpreted as the *path component* of the incoming request because that's what web-servers are programmed to do.

  - Fun-fact: HTTP requests **do not** (normally) contain a fully-qualified URI representation of the request (granted, they *might* have it stored in a private HTTP request header if they're hiding behind a reverse-proxy, and that also applies here as you're on Azure App Services (see the `X-WAWS-Unencoded-URL` header, but that's not fully-qualified...), but anyway).

    - Inside a HTTP request, there is no *URI scheme* or "protocol"  substirng: the server knows if the request is coming from `http:` or `https:` based on the incoming port-number and TLS exchange anyway.
    - The [*authority* part](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.2) of the URI will be sent separately in the `Host:` header.
    - So it's only the [*path* part](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.3) and optional [*query* parts](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.4) that gets sent in the HTTP `GET /path/goes/here` part.
    - While any [`#fragment` part](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.5) *won't be sent to the server at all*.

So in this case, the request that you logged there **is perfectly valid** because there's no prohibition on colons (whether percent-encoded or not) in the *path component* of an  absolute URI or "rooted" URI. [It's only *relative URIs paths* that cannot contain a `:` in their initial path-segment](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.5:%7E:text=In%20addition%2C%20a%20URI%20reference%0A%20%20%20(Section%204.1)%20may%20be%20a%20relative%2Dpath%20reference%2C%20in%20which%20case%20the%0A%20%20%20first%20path%20segment%20cannot%20contain%20a%20colon%20(%22%3A%22)%20character.) as that renders them ambiguously formatted.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I understand that, but the problem which we are facing is that the request like shown on the attached screenshot is entering our IIS rewrite pipeline, then is evaluated until it reaches the rule which adds a trailing slash at the end of URL and then the redirection is being made. So  https://example.com/http:/google.com is being redirected to to google and that's not a desired outcome for us.

Comment: @95XF Just change your `<rewrite>` rules to reject requests with paths containing colons. But if you're asking for help with your rewrite rules, you need to include them in your question-post.

Comment: We have quite a few of them, but only the the one with adding the trailing slash is relevant to the case, so I will add that one.

Comment: You don't need to change all of them - just add a new rule at the very top (with `stopProcessing="true"`) which will match any requests with slashes-that-you-don't-like and reject them - **but** it's bad-practice to handle requests differently simply based on  trailing slashes _alone_.

Comment: The problem is that with the problematic URLs, only the part starting with the second http/https is evaluated inside the rewrite pipeline, so in case of https://example.com/http:/google.com, only the http:/google.com part is taken into account (as shown in the first screenshot).

Comment: @95XF It sounds like your `<rewrite>` rules were written incorrectly then, because what you're describing would only happen if those rewrite rules were using _reconstituted_ fully-qualified URIs (i.e. you're concatenting the HTTP `Host:` header with the Request Path) - **don't do that** and you won't have this problem. You should only ever use `{HTTP_HOST}` in a `<condition>` by itself - and to not re-create full URIs - that's how vulnerabilities like _request-smuggling_ happen...

Comment: But like I said before the URL split happens even before the first rewrite rule is being evaluated, so they cannot be the culprit here.

Comment: In which case you should move the `rewriteModule`'s registration to the top of the `<system.webServer><modules>` list so it gets invoked before the others then. (In Azure App Services this is done by using a XDT file to apply the change to your `ApplicationHost.config` file) - BTW, don't confuse that `<modules>` element with the (now _very obsolete_) `<system.web><httpModules>` from WebForms days....